# Mathematical technique to check intersection

Tags: sequence, intersection, plane

Imagine there is a **very very large room** in the shape of a hollow cube. There are magic balls hanging in the air at fixed discrete positions of the room. No magic ball has another one exactly above it. If we take an **imaginary horizontal plane of infinite area** and pass through the cube, how can we be sure that the plane doesn't cut through any of the magic balls ?

The height of a magic ball is given as a function of its position (x and y). The distribution is such a way that some balls are at the same height while other are at different heights.
Let the function be
          `z = axy + bx + cy`
 where a,b,c are positive integer constants.
The positions (x-axis and y-axis values) and also the height (z) are discrete values (for simplicity, we can consider them positive integers).

*If the ball distribution function was z=10xy+8x+4y, then it is impossible to have a z value of 15 or 21. So a plane at z=15 or z=21 would not cut any of the balls! In fact, in this case, any plane with a height (z = any odd number) would not cut through the balls. It is noticeable that there a some planes with height as even numbers that donot cut through the balls.*

We do not want to find the heights of  all the magic balls and compare it with the height of the horizontal plane, as that would be like trying all the possible combinations and would take very long time even on a computer.

Our aim is to find a fast method by which we can tell whether a given value of z (height) can be produced by any pair of (x,y) (positions).**If a given z cannot be produced, then a plane at that height doesn't cut through any balls!**
The question is also similar to finding whether a given number is present in a sequence produced by a function of two variables.

It would a great help if U could give me any suggestions to solve this problem. Thank You.
(I have already tried evolutionary computing like GA,PSO,DE,SA etc. The method needs to be deterministic).

Comment: Does the plane cut through the entire cube? ie. it's area is bigger than the horizontal area of the cube?

Comment: http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html ?

Comment: Balls are fixed and have no extent? So you have a set of integer points (x,y,z) such that the existence of one point (a,b,c) means that the set contains no points (a,b,d) for d>c, right? And you want to find some w such that the set contains no points with w as the last coordinate? And presumably, you can pre-sort or arrange your set of points, and want to answer the question quickly thereafter?

But your next statement seems to aim for something different: "...whether a given value of z can be produced by any pair of (x,y) (positions).".

Comment: Without knowing anything more about the function that produces z from (x,y), it is impossible to determine the highest value of z reached within the bounding volume in a better fashion than exhaustive search.

Comment: This question needs more information, a practical explanation of a given example would be a good start.

Comment: I think some clarification would help. Is there a ball at every possible (x,y) location? Are you not able to store all the balls in memory? (ie. are we allowed to sort the balls?, for instance)

Comment: If the plane is absolutely horizontal, it is trivial to determine whether there is a plane that doesn't touch any of the balls - just map all the balls onto a 1-dimentional line and (knowing their radii) check if there are any points that are not covered.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Blue, I think we're missing something because I had the same exact idea. Use a simple range-based "chopping" method to chop away from a 0-Z range all the height ranges covered by the balls extents. If there is anything left after that, those are the ranges the plane could exist in that would not touch any balls.

Comment: The suggestion to "just map all the balls onto a 1-dimentional line" won't work because the poster said "We do not want to find the heights of all the magic balls".  To do that, there would have to be MaxX * MaxY calculations, then a scan to see if there are any "gaps" in the results.

Comment: The statement "it is impossible to have a z value of 15 or 21" is wrong, unless the domain of x and y is Z, rather than R. Is the radius of the balls 1?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a lot of balls in the room. The room height is from z=A to z=B. What you're interested in is whether any are at height z. To do that without necessarily iterating through all the balls, you need to start by assuming that the range A to B is empty and iterate through the balls, marking parts of this range as full, until it is either full completely or there are no balls. In the former case, no plane will satisfy, but you haven't iterated through all the balls to know that. In the latter case, you have ranges of z in which there are no balls and you can use these to check more than one plane easily, however at the initial cost of iterating through all balls.